# How to access the object field in a constructor function-try-block?

Tags: c++, constructor, function-try-block

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass::MyClass(std::string name) try 
        : name(std::move(name)),
          someOtherField(WillProbablyThrowSomeException())  {
    } catch (std::runtime_error &e) {
        std::cout << name << " " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string name;
    SomeOtherClass someOtherField;
}
```

I want to access some fields of the object from the constructor function-try-block. If I do just `name` it would be illegal, since it's already moved by the time the catch-block is reached. If I do `this->name` it would also be illegal, since the object is in undefined state (is it?). Is there a way to access this variable somehow?

Comment: I think `this->name` is fine, you can use these fields to initialize other fields - `someOtherField(WillProbablyThrowSomeException(this->name))` is legal so I do not see why the catch block would be any different, it should run before any "deinitialization".

Comment: It seems that the answer is no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an object in the catch, it is in the defined state of fully destructed. You are required to exit the catch block with a throw (possibly implicitly). At this point the data that was in `name` has been lost.

> Before any catch clauses of a function-try-block on a constructor are
> entered, all fully-constructed members and bases have already been
> destroyed.
>
> The behavior is undefined if the catch-clause of a function-try-block
> used on a constructor or a destructor accesses a base or a non-static
> member of the object.
>
> Every catch-clause in the function-try-block for a constructor must
> terminate by throwing an exception. If the control reaches the end of
> such handler, the current exception is automatically rethrown as if by
> throw;. The return statement is not allowed in any catch clause of a
> constructor's function-try-block.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I was totally wrong about function try blocks, they can only modify the exception

Comment: Yeah I suspected as much and started to search the text of the standard...